# anacondaは1000人規模の会社で働く人が、業務外の個人での学習のために使う場合は無償？

Tags: python, anaconda

anacondaは1000人規模の会社で働く人が、業務外の個人での学習のために使う場合は無償という理解でよいのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

公式サイトの[Terms of Service](https://legal.anaconda.com/policies/en/?name=terms-of-service)に下記が記載されている通り(カッコ内は拙訳です)、業務や研究に一切関係しない学習用途であれば「商業活動」に該当しないため所属がどこであろうと無償です。

> To avoid confusion, “commercial activities” are any use of the Repository which is NOT:
> (混乱を避けるため、下記のいずれにも該当しないリポジトリ利用が「商業活動」です)
> * use solely by an individual using for personal, non-business purposes
> (* ビジネスを目的としない、独立した個人による個人的な利用)

ただし個人の活動と企業のR&D活動の境界は非常にあいまいです。
今後企業の商品開発にシフトする可能性がある場合や不安な場合は、利用規約の通り問い合わせするのが最も安全です。

> Please reach out to us for confirmation or to apply for a fee exemption for research usage by visiting https://.... Approval is at the sole discretion of Anaconda.
> (確認や研究用途の無料申請の場合はhttps://...から我々にご連絡ください。承認はAnacondaが独自に行います)

有料かどうかの判定はAnacondaが独自に行うと記載されているように、無料利用者の判断が誤りで商業活動であると判断された場合には相応の対処をされる可能性があります。
なお、この回答も回答者個人の解釈であり、正しくない可能性がありますのでご注意ください。

参考資料:
[【プログラミング】anaconda の有償回避方法と代替案](https://xinformation.hatenadiary.com/entry/2022/06/28/005425)